# How do I model a "Connections" relation between Doctor-Patient on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby on Rails for my dissertation creating a E-health monitoring web application for Doctors and Patients. My question is:

Is there any simple approach to creating an `Connection` option as seen on `LinkedIn` that I can use between Doctors and Patients?

I have been thinking about it and my approach would be to create a new entity in my database called `Connection` that will store the `doctor_id` and the `patient_id` attributes.

How would I create the necessary validations required?
E.g For example if a patient is not connected with a doctor they cannot send a message to the doctor or if not connected they cannot see certain information.

I'm looking for an approach or a guide to how I can solve this problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you could approach it is to write a method in the model to make checking the relationship nice and clean. For example, if you wanted to check if a patient was connected with a doctor, you could add something like this to your `Patient` model:

**Patient Model**

```
def connected?(doc)
  return true if Connection.where(:patient_id => self.id, :doctor_id => doc.id).count > 0
  false
end
```

Then, whenever you have an instance of a patient and doctor in your app, you can check if they are connected by passing the `connected?` method. For example, assume you have your objects as `@patient` and `@doctor`. You could check their connection like so:

```
if @patient.connected?(@doctor)
  # do stuff, like send message
end
```

Of course, how you approach using this method can vary greatly depending on what you're trying to accomplish. It can become really messy to keep writing `if` statements all over the place. But, I tend to get the app working first and then focus on cleaning the code.

**EDIT**

As Phlip mentions, if your `Connection` model doesn't contain any data, it is simpler to get rid of the model and use a [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) relationship between `Patient` and `Doctor`.

I would still use a method in the `Patient` and/or `Doctor` models to check whether the connection exists. Then, if you ever need to add data to the connection, you could easily create a `Connection` model and not have to edit your controllers/views.

Comment: Downvoted because the OP should start with `has_and_belongs_to_many` (unless a Connection itself has any data, such as a date or a referral detail.) Then the `.where().count` becomes merely `patient.doctors.find(doctor.id).count`. Or even less.

Comment: Great point, @Phlip -- I've edited my answer with your comment. While this is simpler, I would still use a model method to keep controllers and views clean.